# Split column in dataframe in R at a '%' character

Tags: r, dataframe

I cannot adapt the existing solutions on this forum that address splitting dataframe columns into two.

I have this dataframe (which funnily enough, has already been split to make it look like  this), **that I need to be split at the % symbol**

[image]

The end result I would like, is the 32%, 35%, 54%... 55% will be deleted. So it is just two columns of data. This data is scraped from a website.

Thank you

Comment: strsplit(x=Long,split="[%]")[[1]][2]

Comment: Only for a single element, sorry. Otherwise: sapply(your.df$Long,function(x) strsplit(x,"[%]")[[1]][2])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df$Long<-sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Long), split= "\\%"),'[',2)           
   Long Short
1  239   497
2  142   269
3  216   186
4   96    52
5   93   184
6  160   142
7   96    79
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
df$Long <- paste0(unlist(lapply(strsplit(a, "%"), `[[`, 1)), "%")
```

It splits each string in `Long` column by `"%"` and gets the first element in each split. Then it adds the `"%"` to the end of the resulting vector.

Answer (score 1):

I would use tidyr and dplyr for this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data.frame(Long = c("32% 239", "35% 142", "54% 216"), Short = c(497,269,186), stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
    separate(Long, c("Long_percent","Long_2"), sep = " ") %>%
    select(-Long_percent)
```

Or you can also use a regex, which could be useful if the data is not so well formed:

```
data.frame(Long = c("32% 239", "35% 142", "54% 216"), Short = c(497,269,186), stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
    mutate(Long = gsub("[0-9%]+ ", "", Long, perl = T))
```